# Can i get the data from userdefault in suspended mode in ios?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am creating an application on beacon. In beacon when the application in suspended mode that time also called `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region` when i am entering particular region but i want is data from the `NSUserDefaults` and set it to local notification. I have already set a data in to `NSUserDefaults` when the application enter to region i want to get a data from the userdefault.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything, was something not working as expected ?

Comment: yes i tried. but did not get data from the userdefault when in suspended mode.

Comment: might be if i get data in background mode from the user default but i want in suspended mode. because the main focus of beacon is in suspended mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard a similar report of this in a deleted answer to a question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347464/1461050.  Since you probably cannot see that question, here is what the user reported:

> I have an extremely annoying bug in iOS: 1. Phone battery is done and it is recharge. 2. App is being waken in the background by a beacon detection (car beacon in our case). 3. AppDidFinishLaunchWithOptions is being called (as expected) 4. the NSUserDefault values at that time are null (it appears that it is related to the fact that NSUser defaults are under some kind of protection).

I have not reproduced this myself, but figured it is worth sharing that other folks have reported having trouble getting access to `NSUserDefaults` in certain modes.

Comment: then is there any way to get data?

Comment: You might be unable to access any part of the (encrypted) filesystem until the user unlocks his device, just a guess. Your best shot is to contact Apple, with the developer program you have two free questions per year to ask: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/